# PHP Delete all files that are empty in a Directory and any sub directories

Tags: php

This is what I have but its not working nor giving me an errors:

```
$MyDir = "C:/some_folder/"; 

// DELETE ALL EMPTY FILES
$filesDVA = glob($MyDir.'*'); // get all file names
foreach($filesDVA as $file){ // iterate files
  if(empty($file))
    unlink($file); // delete file
}
```

I would like to delete the empty files that are in the main directory and sub directories and if possible check if the directory is empty also and if it is delete it too.

UPDATE:

```
foreach (glob($MyDir . '*') as $file) {
    if (is_writable($file) && filesize($file) < (1024 * 1)) {
        unlink($file);
    }
}
```

It removes the empty files (or files that are less than 1kb but it gives me an error when trying to access the directories saying Permission denied for each directory, so it will NOT delete the empty directories or the files that are within the sub directories.

Comment: You need to also check if the file exists before deleting

Comment: if your other syntax is correct, $file will never be empty. try if(empty(file_get_contents($file)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`empty($file)` doesn't check that the file referenced by `$file` is empty, it checks that the *variable* `$file` is empty. I.e., if `$file` contains an empty string `""` or `null` then `empty($file)` will return true. Since your `$file` contains a non-empty string (the name of the file), `empty($file)` will always return false, regardless of the file contents. You want to check that [`filesize($file)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) is zero.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my code that works to delete the files but will not delete the empty directories or the empty files within the sub directories. Please See The Updated Code Above.

Comment: You need `rmdir()` to delete a directory. If you want to recurse, you might use the [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) class.

Comment: OK, now I'm totally lost... let me see if I can figure this out... or if you get a second to write me an example.